# T4Scaffolding access generic collection T properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

Given the following class:

```
public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ...more properties...

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and my ps1 entry code:

```
$model = Get-ProjectType $EntityName -Project $Project

Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $controllerName -Template ControllerTemplate `
    -Model @{ Namespace = $namespace; T = [MarshalByRefObject]$model; } `
    -SuccessMessage "Added ControllerTemplate output at {0}" `
    -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$Force
```

where $model is the Post class.

how would i gain access to "Tag" object properties?

I have "Tags" ICollection as a EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef.

I noticed that most of the mvcscaffolding is using Get-RelatedEntities  to unwrap the generics - is this the only way to access the Tag properties?

Comment: Attaching vs debugger didn't help.  Shows a proxy object and I was unable to cast to a valid known type in watch window. So I went with the Get-RelatedEntities way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first part of this video. It will show you how to collect properties from classes in Visual Studio.

EDIT:

If you do not have the time to view the video... Just use this snippet in the package manager console.

(Get-ProjectType Tag).Children | Where-Object{$*.Kind -eq 4} | ForEach{$*}

I think it is easier to find all properties with powershell and then send it into the T4, it´s hard work to use C# in the T4 to collect information.

[T4Scaffolding in Visual Studio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hrD5MAXuIg&feature=share&list=UUaCFN2DfemnttPoGH3LLDiQ)

Regards
Uffe